# Bitbake do_package_qa error: Wrong location

Tags: linux, package, yocto, bitbake, openblas

I'm trying to build openblas-0.3.5 with Yocto (Rocko) for my 64-bit Armv8-A. I've found this recipe online and i tweaked it a bit. But i got the following error:

**Error:**

```
ERROR: openblas-0.3.5-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: openblas path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/openblas/0.3.5-r0/packages-split/openblas/usr/lib/libopenblas.so' [dev-so]
WARNING: openblas-0.3.5-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: openblas: found library in wrong location: /usr/lib/libopenblas.so.0
openblas: found library in wrong location: /usr/lib/libopenblas_armv8-r0.3.5.so
openblas: found library in wrong location: /usr/lib/libopenblas.so [libdir]
ERROR: openblas-0.3.5-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: openblas-0.3.5-r0 do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
```

Below is my openblas.bb file:

```
#
#   Copyright (c) 2016 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
#   Copyright (c) 2019 Luxoft Sweden AB
#
#   SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
#

DESCRIPTION = "OpenBLAS is an optimized BLAS library based on GotoBLAS2 1.13 BSD version."
SUMMARY = "OpenBLAS : An optimized BLAS library"
AUTHOR = "Alexander Leiva <norxander@gmail.com>"
HOMEPAGE = "http://www.openblas.net/"
SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"

DEPENDS = "make"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=5adf4792c949a00013ce25d476a2abc0"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/archive/v${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "579bda57f68ea6e9074bf5780e8620bb"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "0950c14bd77c90a6427e26210d6dab422271bc86f9fc69126725833ecdaa0e85"

S = "${WORKDIR}/OpenBLAS-${PV}"

do_compile () {
        oe_runmake HOSTCC="${BUILD_CC}" \
        CC="${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc ${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}" \
        CROSS_SUFFIX=${HOST_PREFIX} \
        ONLY_CBLAS=1 USE_THREAD=0 \
        HOSTCC="${BUILD_CC}" \
        TARGET=ARMV8 BINARY=64
}

do_install() {
        oe_runmake HOSTCC="${BUILD_CC}" \
        CC="${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc ${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}" \
        CROSS_SUFFIX=${HOST_PREFIX} \
        ONLY_CBLAS=1 USE_THREAD=0 \
        HOSTCC="${BUILD_CC}" \
        TARGET=ARMV8 BINARY=64 \
        PREFIX=${D}/usr \
        install     

        rm -rf ${D}${bindir}
        rm -rf ${D}${libdir}/cmake
} 

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/*"
#FILES_${PN}-dev = "${libdir}/* ${includedir}"

INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "staticdev"
```

**Alternative way of removing errors:**
I replaced -

```
PREFIX=${D}/usr \
```

with

```
PREFIX="${D}/opt/${PN}" \
```

and

```
FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/*"
#FILES_${PN}-dev = "${libdir}/* ${includedir}"
```

with

```
FILES_${PN}     += "/opt/${PN}"
FILES_${PN}-dev += "/opt/${PN}/lib/lib${PN}.so"
#FILES_${PN}-dbg += "/opt/${PN}/lib/.debug"
```

**ISSUES:**

1) After doing this, openblas was built without error. But, When i had to work with openblas, after board boot-up, I had to manually copy all the files from /opt/openblas to /usr/lib64/ and /usr/include/.

2) I couldn't find openblas in my sysroots-components folder in `build/tmp/sysroots-components/aarch64/openblas` .

3) Couldn't use openblas as dependency of any other recipe. since, it was installed in /opt and not in /usr. (no openblas in sysroots-components)

**So, my question is, How do i solve these issues and install openblas in** `/usr/lib64` **instead of** `/usr/lib` **or** `/opt` **??**

Comment: Change `PREFIX=${D}/usr` in do_install()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recipe for ARMV8

```
DESCRIPTION = "OpenBLAS is an optimized BLAS library based on GotoBLAS2 1.13 BSD version."
SUMMARY = "OpenBLAS : An optimized BLAS library"
AUTHOR = "Alexander Leiva <norxander@gmail.com>"
HOMEPAGE = "http://www.openblas.net/"
SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libgfortran"
DEPENDS += " make libgfortran"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=5adf4792c949a00013ce25d476a2abc0"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/archive/v${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "48637eb29f5b492b91459175dcc574b1"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "5ef38b15d9c652985774869efd548b8e3e972e1e99475c673b25537ed7bcf394"

S = "${WORKDIR}/OpenBLAS-${PV}"

FLOATABI = "${@bb.utils.contains("TUNE_FEATURES", "vfp", bb.utils.contains("TUNE_FEATURES", "callconvention-hard", " -mfloat-abi=hard", " -mfloat-abi=softfp", d), "" ,d)}"


def map_arch(a, d):
  import re
  if re.match('i.86$', a): return 'ATOM'
  elif re.match('x86_64$', a): return 'ATOM'
  elif re.match('aarch32$', a): return 'ARMV7'
  elif re.match('aarch64$', a): return 'ARMV8'
  return a

def map_bits(a, d):
  import re
  if re.match('i.86$', a): return 32
  elif re.match('x86_64$', a): return 64
  elif re.match('aarch32$', a): return 32
  elif re.match('aarch64$', a): return 64
  return 64

do_compile () {
  oe_runmake HOSTCC="${BUILD_CC} " \
                     CC="${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc ${FLOATABI} ${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}" \
                     PREFIX=${exec_prefix} \
                     CROSS_SUFFIX=${HOST_PREFIX} \
                     ONLY_CBLAS=1 BINARY='${@map_bits(d.getVar('TARGET_ARCH', True), d)}' \
                     TARGET='ARMV8'
}

do_install() {
  install -d ${D}${libdir}
  install -d ${D}${libdir}/cmake
  install -d ${D}${libdir}/pkgconfig
  oe_runmake HOSTCC="${BUILD_CC}" \
                     CC="${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc ${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}" \
                     PREFIX=${exec_prefix} \
                     CROSS_SUFFIX=${HOST_PREFIX} \
                     ONLY_CBLAS=1 BINARY='${@map_bits(d.getVar('TARGET_ARCH', True), d)}' \
                     TARGET='${@map_arch(d.getVar('TARGET_ARCH', True), d)}' \
                     DESTDIR=${D} \
                     install

  cp -r ${D}/usr/lib/* ${D}/usr/lib64/
  rm -rf ${D}/usr/lib
  rm -rf ${D}/usr/bin
}

RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev = ""
RDEPENDS_${PN}-staticdev = ""

FILES_${PN}-libs = "${libdir}/*"

FILES_${PN}     += "/usr/lib64"
FILES_${PN}-dev = "${includedir} ${libdir}/lib${PN}.so"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "staticdev"
```

Answer (score 0):

`do_install` needs to pass the correct `${libdir}` as the Makefile assumes that `$PREFIX/lib` is correct when for your platform it is not.

Along side `PREFIX` also pass `OPENBLAS_LIBRARY_DIR=${libdir}`.

Comment: hi ross, I tried this and it didn't work. Got the same errors. I have built it successfully now though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use this lib, I use this recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "OpenBLAS is an optimized BLAS library based on GotoBLAS2 1.13 BSD version."
SUMMARY = "OpenBLAS : An optimized BLAS library"
AUTHOR = "Alexander Leiva <norxander@gmail.com>"
HOMEPAGE = "http://www.openblas.net/"
SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libgfortran"
DEPENDS += " make libgfortran"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=5adf4792c949a00013ce25d476a2abc0"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/archive/v${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "48637eb29f5b492b91459175dcc574b1"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "5ef38b15d9c652985774869efd548b8e3e972e1e99475c673b25537ed7bcf394"

S = "${WORKDIR}/OpenBLAS-${PV}"

FLOATABI = "${@bb.utils.contains("TUNE_FEATURES", "vfp", bb.utils.contains("TUNE_FEATURES", "callconvention-hard", " -mfloat-abi=hard", " -mfloat-abi=softfp", d), "" ,d)}"


def map_arch(a, d):
  import re
  if re.match('i.86$', a): return 'ATOM'
  elif re.match('x86_64$', a): return 'ATOM'
  elif re.match('aarch32$', a): return 'ARMV7'
  elif re.match('aarch64$', a): return 'ARMV8'
  return a

def map_bits(a, d):
  import re
  if re.match('i.86$', a): return 32
  elif re.match('x86_64$', a): return 64
  elif re.match('aarch32$', a): return 32
  elif re.match('aarch64$', a): return 64
  return 32

do_compile () {
  oe_runmake HOSTCC="${BUILD_CC} " \
                     CC="${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc ${FLOATABI} ${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}" \
                     PREFIX=${exec_prefix} \
                     CROSS_SUFFIX=${HOST_PREFIX} \
                     ONLY_CBLAS=1 BINARY='${@map_bits(d.getVar('TARGET_ARCH', True), d)}' \
                     TARGET='ARMV7'
}

do_install() {
  oe_runmake HOSTCC="${BUILD_CC}" \
                     CC="${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc ${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}" \
                     PREFIX=${exec_prefix} \
                     CROSS_SUFFIX=${HOST_PREFIX} \
                     ONLY_CBLAS=1 BINARY='${@map_bits(d.getVar('TARGET_ARCH', True), d)}' \
                     TARGET='${@map_arch(d.getVar('TARGET_ARCH', True), d)}' \
                     DESTDIR=${D} \
                     install

  rm -rf ${D}${bindir}
  rm -rf ${D}${libdir}/cmake
}

FILES_${PN}     = "${libdir}/*"
FILES_${PN}-dev = "${includedir} ${libdir}/lib${PN}.so"
```

Comment: This recipe is for ARMV7. Even for me, openblas worked on my ARMV7 board. But i'm getting issues on my ARMV8. Openblas is built now. What i did was change TARGET to ARMV8 and binary to 64. 
Then i created, lib64 folder in my openblas image, under usr. Then i copied, contents of usr/lib into usr/lib64. Also, i had to give this for do_package issue --

```RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev = ""
RDEPENDS_${PN}-staticdev = ""

FILES_${PN}-libs = "${libdir}/*"

FILES_${PN}     += "/usr/lib64"
FILES_${PN}-dev = "${includedir} ${libdir}/lib${PN}.so"```